Deleting parts of vcfR objects
I am working on vcfR objects in R, and I need to delete some columns of the vcfR objects in order to perform the downstream analysis. Here is the code to create a example input file :
install.packages("vcfR")

vcfexample = read.vcfR(system.file("extdata", "pinf_sc50.vcf.gz", package = "pinfsc50"))

I have to delete the information in columns 6 to 8 of vcfexample@fix and column 1 of vcf@gt (so that I have missing values instead of the original content). vcfexample@fix and vcf@gt are matrices and array (the class function returns both "matrix" and "array").
I tried the following code lines (following this post : delete parts of a matrix in R) :
file2test@fix[,6:8] = NA

replace_with_na(as.data.frame(file2test@fix[,6:8]))..

as.matrix(replace_with_na(as.data.frame(file2test@fix[,6:8])))

But they only seem to replace the values with an "NA" string (when I check with the is_na, the output is FALSE).
I also tried this :
file2test@fix[,6:8] = ""

But in the output I have empty strings but not missing values.
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Use is.na or are_na, not is_na. When I run vcfexample@fix[,6:8] = NA, all(is.na(vcfexample@fix[,6:8])) returns TRUE. is_na returns FASLE because it is meant to be used on a scalar, not a vector or array.

You're right, thank you so much !
